# How can I access unknown objects at runtime - not their names

Tags: python, global

I am parsing some documents that have sections in some order.  I need to know their order to match some parsing objectives.  Right now I have these lists, here are two

```
possible_seq_1 = [1, '1A', '1B', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, '7A',
           8, 9, '9A', '9B', 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]


possible_seq_2 = [1, '1A', '1B', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, '7A',
           8, 9, '9A(T)', '9B', 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

I want to use the items in the lists above as the keys to a dictionary where the value directs me to the next step

```
my_dict = dict()
aKey =  = '_'.join([str(item) for item in possible_seq_1])
my_dict(aKey) = 'something'
```

Thus when I am processing something later I can simply test whether or not the object matches one of the keys in my dictionary

My question is that I am going to be adding to possible_seq (uences) later some unknown number (right now I have ten alternatives) I key the sequence into my code as I did in this message and then before I run the code I have to make some changes to incorporate my new sequence.  Specifically I have to increment the range in the following

```
my_dict = dict()
for sequence in range(1,10,1):
    dict_key = '_'.join([str(item) for item in possible_seq_ + str(sequence)
    my_dict[dict_key] = something
```

As I was doing this I wondered if Python makes available the objects it knows about because they have been defined in the code.  I figured out that their names are available but I can't figure out how to grab/reference the object itself

That is I thought I could do

```
seq_list = [ item for item in globals() if 'possible_seq' in item if type(item) == list ]
```

However, I get an empty list, this is interesting because the name is a string so globals is giving me a list of the names of objects - I want the actual object not the name this code gives me the names

```
seq_list = [ item for item in globals() if 'possible_seq' in item ]
```

I will admit that as I was working on this question I realized the simpler thing to do was to just add my sequences as lists inside a list of sequences but now I am interested in this other approach just to improve my understanding of Python

Comment: you can use objects as keys in a dictionary and then you can get a list of all the objects by calling `dict.keys()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is that `globals()` is a dictionary, not a list, so just iterating over the items in `globals()` gets only their names. Since you want to check whether `possible_seq` is in each name, you could, you could use the `.items()` method of a dictionary to iterate over both the name and the object:

```
[v for k, v in globals().items() if 'possible_seq' in k]
```

*However*, as you surmise this is not a good approach. *Much* better would be to keep a list of lists, like:

```
possible_seqs = [[1, '1A', '1B', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, '7A',
           8, 9, '9A', '9B', 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
                 [1, '1A', '1B', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, '7A',
           8, 9, '9A(T)', '9B', 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

See [keep data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Comment: thanks I learn so much from this site your link was helpful as well a